# How is number of containers calculated in a AWS EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Let's say I have the following config:

```
Instance type: r5.8xlarge (32 vCore, 256 GiB memory, EBS only storage)
EBS Storage: 100GiB
No. of on demand units: 3995
Per Instance counts = 4 unit
No. of EC2 instances = 3995/4 = 999 (But EMR provisioned 1004 instances)
spark.executor.memoryOverhead=10240mb 
spark.driver.memory=204800mb
spark.executor.memory=51200mb
--executor-cores 7
spark.memory.fraction=0.9
```

From the EMR console, I can see the total number of containers allocated is 826, but this doesn't align with my understanding of the calculation.

Here is my calculation based on above config:

```
No of executors per instance = Instance memory * spark_memory_fraction/(Executor memory + its overhead) = 256GB*0.9/(51+10) = 3.7 executors/instance ~ Math.floor(3.7) =  3 executor/instance
Overall executors = 999 instances * 3 executor/instance = 2997 executors.
```

The number that I see in the console(826 containers or executors) vastly differs from my calculation(2997 executors). Can someone help me understand this how its calculated and why there is so much difference ?

Comment: How many applications are running and do you have Queues created in YARN?

Comment: We have 1 Yarn application and the job succeeds without issues. It runs everyday once successfully. We don't use Yarn Queue Manager. I'm just curious how the number of containers is determined based on the above config ?